# Rest API latency way higher than logs

Tags: rest, networking, paw-app

I have a REST api that's logging a latency of 5 ms consistently for a route, but my API client is recording 222 ms for the total roundtrip time. The latency that `ping` is showing is ~35ms between the web server.

What are some of the possibilities of where the differential lie of 180ms that's adding to the time?

Answer (score 0):

You should try switching HTTP Library in Paw > Preferences > Network which should help with a more accurate latency report. URLSession should be helpful here:
[HTTP Library Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JpoT.png)

- The Paw Team